# Change class="page-numbers" in pagination

Tags: pagination

I'm using the following code ([from here](http://www.ordinarycoder.com/paginate_links-class-ul-li-bootstrap/)) to paginate links:

```
function custom_pagination() {
    global $wp_query;
    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
    $pages = paginate_links( array(
            'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'format' => '?paged=%#%',
            'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
            'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
            'prev_next' => false,
            'type'  => 'array',
            'prev_next'   => TRUE,
            'prev_text'    => __('«'),
            'next_text'    => __('»'),
        ) );
        if( is_array( $pages ) ) {
            $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') == 0 ) ? 1 : get_query_var('paged');
            echo '<ul class="pagination">';
            foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
                    echo "<li>$page</li>";
            }
           echo '</ul>';
        }
}
```

The output of this is using `echo custom_pagination();`:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="page-item">
        <a class="page-numbers" href="example.com/page/1">1</a>          
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can I change the output to this?:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="page-item">
        <a class="page-link" href="example.com/page/1">1</a>          
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to make a bootstrap theme, but I can't seem to replace the `page-numbers` class with the bootstrap `page-link` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `paginate_links()` function, located in [`wp-includes/general-template.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/general-template.php#L3233), doesn't allow for certain parts of the HTML (such as the `page-numbers` class) to be customized.

A simple string replacement will not work due to the way that the classes are generated, as highlighted in this excerpt of code from `paginate_links()`:

```
    $page_links[] = '<a class="prev page-numbers" href="' . esc_url( apply_filters( 'paginate_links', $link ) ) . '">' . $args['prev_text'] . '</a>';
endif;
for ( $n = 1; $n <= $total; $n++ ) :
    if ( $n == $current ) :
        $page_links[] = "<span class='page-numbers current'>" . $args['before_page_number'] . number_format_i18n( $n ) . $args['after_page_number'] . "</span>";
```

Here is an updated version of your `custom_pagination()` function, which uses DOMXpath to to find instances elements with the `page-numbers` class, then a string replacement is done to change the class to `page-link`. For better compatibility with Bootstrap, the `current` class is also replaced with `active`. Finally, `class="mynewclass"` is added to the `<li>` which contains the current item.

```
function wpse247219_custom_pagination() {
    global $wp_query;
    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
    $pages = paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'prev_next' => false,
        'type'  => 'array',
        'prev_next'   => true,
        'prev_text'    => __( '«', 'text-domain' ),
        'next_text'    => __( '»', 'text-domain'),
    ) );
    $output = '';

    if ( is_array( $pages ) ) {
        $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') == 0 ) ? 1 : get_query_var( 'paged' );

        $output .=  '<ul class="pagination">';
        foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
            $output .= "<li>$page</li>";
        }
        $output .= '</ul>';

        // Create an instance of DOMDocument 
        $dom = new \DOMDocument();

        // Populate $dom with $output, making sure to handle UTF-8, otherwise
        // problems will occur with UTF-8 characters.
        $dom->loadHTML( mb_convert_encoding( $output, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8' ) );

        // Create an instance of DOMXpath and all elements with the class 'page-numbers' 
        $xpath = new \DOMXpath( $dom );

        // http://stackoverflow.com/a/26126336/3059883
        $page_numbers = $xpath->query( "//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' page-numbers ')]" );

        // Iterate over the $page_numbers node...
        foreach ( $page_numbers as $page_numbers_item ) {

            // Add class="mynewclass" to the <li> when its child contains the current item.
            $page_numbers_item_classes = explode( ' ', $page_numbers_item->attributes->item(0)->value );
            if ( in_array( 'current', $page_numbers_item_classes ) ) {          
                $list_item_attr_class = $dom->createAttribute( 'class' );
                $list_item_attr_class->value = 'mynewclass';
                $page_numbers_item->parentNode->appendChild( $list_item_attr_class );
            }

            // Replace the class 'current' with 'active'
            $page_numbers_item->attributes->item(0)->value = str_replace( 
                            'current',
                            'active',
                            $page_numbers_item->attributes->item(0)->value );

            // Replace the class 'page-numbers' with 'page-link'
            $page_numbers_item->attributes->item(0)->value = str_replace( 
                            'page-numbers',
                            'page-link',
                            $page_numbers_item->attributes->item(0)->value );
        }

        // Save the updated HTML and output it.
        $output = $dom->saveHTML();
    }

    return $output;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
echo wpse247219_custom_pagination();
```

**Generated HTML:**

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="mynewclass"><span class="page-link active">1</span></li>
    <li><a class="page-link" href="http://localhost/page/2/">2</a></li>
    <li><a class="page-link" href="http://localhost/page/3/">3</a></li>
    <li><span class="page-link dots">…</span></li>
    <li><a class="page-link" href="http://localhost/page/5/">5</a></li>
    <li><a class="next page-link" href="http://localhost/page/2/">»</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This code works great, but one last thing, how would I go about in changing "$page_links[] = "<span class='page-numbers current'>' " as well? I would like to change the class=''page-numbers current' to class=''page-numbers active'

Comment: Glad that worked out for you! I've updated my answer so that *current* has been replaced with *active* :-)

Comment: Actually, how there a way to add a class just to the <li> when I'm on the the <span class="page-link active">1</span>? e.g   <li class='mynewclass'><span class="page-link active">1</span></li>.

Comment: That's doable. Updated my answer so that the `<li>` containing the current item gets `class="mynewclass"` added to it.

Comment: Wonderful! Everything is working now.

Comment: Are there drawback with this considering speed / performance?

Answer (score 1):

Work on this today, compatible wordpress 5.5.1 with bootstrap 4 :

```php
        <?php
            $pagination = paginate_links( array(
              'base' => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
              'format' => '?paged=%#%',
              'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
              'total' => $query_accueil->max_num_pages,
              'prev_text' => '<i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i>',
              'next_text' => '<i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i>',
              'type' => 'array'
            ) );
        ?>
        <?php if ( ! empty( $pagination ) ) : ?>
          <nav aria-label="page navigation">
            <ul class="pagination">
              <?php foreach ( $pagination as $key => $page_link ) : ?>
                <li class="page-item
                  <?php
                      $link = htmlspecialchars($page_link);
                      $link = str_replace( ' current', '', $link);
                      if ( strpos( $page_link, 'current' ) !== false ) { echo ' active'; }
                  ?>
                ">
                  <?php
                    if ( $link ) {
                      $link = str_replace( 'page-numbers', 'page-link', $link);
                    }
                    echo htmlspecialchars_decode($link);
                  ?>
                </li>
              <?php endforeach ?>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        <?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tracking through this, it appears that there isn't a way to pass a class through the `paginate_links` function. So based on the `custom_pagination` function, here's how I'd rewrite it:

```
function custom_pagination() {
    global $wp_query;

    // No idea why this line was in the if statement originally...
    $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 );

    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

    $pages = paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => $paged,
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'prev_next' => false,
        'type'  => 'array',
        'prev_next'   => TRUE,
        'prev_text'    => __('«'),
        'next_text'    => __('»'),
    ) );

    if( is_array( $pages ) ) {

        echo '<ul class="pagination">' .
                 str_replace( 'class="page-numbers"', 'class="page-link"', implode( '', $pages ) .
             '</ul>';

    }
}
```

Didn't test this, please let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

In your last line of code you forgot a closing ). Here is the correct line:

```
echo '<ul class="pagination">' . str_replace( 'class="page-numbers"', 'class="page-link"' ), implode( '', $pages ) . '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution using jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $(".pagination .page-item .page-numbers").addClass("page-link");
    $(".pagination .page-item .page-link").removeClass("page-numbers");

});
```

Same approach can be used for other classes like `current` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but the simplest solution I've found is using `preg_replace`:

```
$pages = paginate_links( array(
    ... // your existing pagination args
) );

$pages = preg_replace('/page-numbers/', 'page-link', $pages);
```